# How to handle AngularJS code in barcode scanner method for cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have a req. where, I need to scan a qr code and send it to server, then based on success message from server, show a different screen.

Issue:After scanning, instead of directly going to success screen, app returns to previous screen from where i invoked the scanner and then goes to success. How do I avoid the app going previous screen from where i invoked the scanner instead go to success message directly.

Code:

```css
 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              
              console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
              console.log("We got a qrcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

            
            if(result.cancelled){
              $location.path('/choose');
            }
            else{
              text = result.text + '';
              //involves server http req.
              processResult(text);

            }
            
            processResult(text){
              if(resp.from serve true) 
              //reacts back to app nd tehn navigate
              {$location.path('/success');}
             }
```